# Docker image does not rebuild after code change

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am playing around with a docker project that builds and starts with

`docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /$(pwd)/example/proto:/proto <image-name>`

Inside it is a gradle based java application, about which I would like to get to know somewhat more, so I started to modify its source, adding some logs etc.

I tried to rebuild and rerun the docker image the above way but the results of my modifications don't seem to visible, the logs aren't printed etc.
I removed the image with `docker rmi`, but after every rebuild it seems to be the same image is being created. `docker images` always shows it is created 3 weeks ago and the image id is always the same

Checking on the application level the build directory contains the newly compiled java classes, so apparently on that level my changes are in effect, but it seems docker still uses the old code

Any help would be appreciated

Updated: `Dockerfile`

```
FROM gradle:7.0.0-jdk11 as cache
RUN mkdir -p /home/gradle/cache_home
RUN mkdir -p /proto
RUN touch /proto/any.proto
ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME /home/gradle/cache_home
COPY build.gradle /home/gradle/java-code/
COPY gradle.properties /home/gradle/java-code/
WORKDIR /home/gradle/java-code
RUN gradle build -i --no-daemon || return 0

FROM gradle:7.0.0-jdk11 as runner
COPY --from=cache /home/gradle/cache_home /home/gradle/.gradle
COPY . /usr/src/java-code/
WORKDIR /usr/src/java-code
EXPOSE 8888 
ENTRYPOINT ["gradle", "bootRun", "-i"]
```

Comment: `docker rmi` shows some `Deleted ... XXX` images?

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, two `Untagged: ...` followed by several `Deleted: ...`

Comment: and after that if you do `docker images | grep XXX` - they are not shown, right?

Comment: @Eugene: If you mean the "main" image for which I issued `docker rmi` that is not present in `docker images` afterwards. Those several numbers among `Deleted: ...` those I think I never see listed in `docker images`

Comment: here is a sample output of what I mean : `$ docker rmi zero-x/spring-cloud-sandbox
Untagged: zero-x/spring-cloud-sandbox:latest
Deleted: sha256:d2e7e86ff8b8750cf26bb3aaf5e411146078a68e4f6ba2887506cc2e0e4667d6
$ docker images | grep zero
$` from my local current environment

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, I do the same and the rmi'd image is not among `docker images` afterwards

Comment: oh wow. this is really awkward then. u have multiple docker(s)? I really can't think of what is going on

Comment: @Eugene: By "multiple docker(s)" you mean more than one different Docker Desktops installed on my computer? For that the answer is no. I am btw regularly building and deleting other docker images locally through maven-docker-plugin  with which there don't seem to be any similar problems, they are successfully built with a "created 1 minutes ago" and contain my latest changes. This case seems as if it would not be a fresh local build but instead some existing image is downloaded from somewhere hence the "created 3 weeks ago". But that's where my otherwise limited docker knowledge comes in :/

Comment: What's that `-v` option?  (Is the content of a volume hiding the updated content in the image?)  What's in the Dockerfile; do you need to build the jar file outside Docker before building the Docker image?

Comment: @hammerfest Can you include the commands you are using to build the image, and the Dockerfile, and the full commands you are running with

Comment: @Matt: I updated the question accordingly. The application is a gRPC server which generates java classes from protobuf during the build and the -v is mapping the proto directories. Regarding the build, I now tried to execute `gradle clean` which removed the compiled java classes from my local machine and then the `docker run`. As a result once again the 3 weeks old docker image has appeared while there seem to be no java classes re-generated on my local machine, which seems to support that it is actually rather downloading an older image than compiling a new one containing my local changes

Comment: @hammerfest and the `docker build` command?

Comment: @Matt: There is no `docker build` command I use currently. I go by the app's readme which gives only this `docker run` command which I assumed would give me a local build and then an app startup. Truth is I am not a docker nor a gradle expert so there are several unknown variables for me in the flow yet :/

Comment: aha. a local build will put your updates in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `docker build` will send your local changes to your local docker deamon to be built into an image.

```
cd projectWithDockerfile
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t me/gradlethingy .
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /$(pwd)/example/proto:/proto me/gradlethingy
```

Without the `build` I'm guessing you are pulling in their `<image-name>` from the net each time.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it results in a newly built docker image including my changes. No compiled java classes visible in my local machine filesystem though (no `build` directory created). I will try to study some on the distinction what happens in the local filesystem and what inside the docker container...

Comment: To get file onto the local mounted volume, that would need be done after `build`, from the `run` of the image.  Is the `build` dir something the `"gradle", "bootRun", "-i"` command should be populating?

Comment: The `build` directory is created in the application directory on my local filesystem, i.e. `C:\Users\...\gradlethingy\build` after I issue `gradle build` with no docker commands involved, and it contains the latest compiled java classes. I noticed that when I issue `docker build...` and then `docker run...` then this directory is not being created in the local filesystem, yet the created docker image contains the latest java code